# Creating asset on Bigchaindb server using http call

Tags: blockchain, bigchaindb

I have created an account on bigchaindb site. Now I want to post some data to online server using http call by postman. I got it that I need to mention api_key and app_id in header. What I need to keep in body and what other parameters should be passed ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what all you need to tell Postman, but here's a start:

method = POST

URL = https://test.bigchainb.com/api/v1/transactions?mode=commit

**Headers**

app_id: value

app_key: value

Content-Type: application/json

**Body**

The final, signed (fulfilled) transaction goes in the body, but I'm not sure what format Postman expects it in. Maybe a Unicode JSON string?

To construct a valid signed transaction, you should probably use one of the BigchainDB drivers, and if you're doing that, then why not also use the same driver to POST the transaction to the BigchainDB Testnet? Here's a list of drivers:

http://docs.bigchaindb.com/projects/server/en/master/drivers-clients/index.html

Comment: Is there any tutorial which explains each component of http request body and what all information we need to provide in the body part ?

Comment: All that goes in the HTTP body is one BigchainDB transaction. BigchainDB 2.0 requires that the transaction be a v2 transaction. The spec for such transactions can be found at https://github.com/bigchaindb/BEPs/tree/master/13